# Batch file that returns folder size

Tags: size, directory, dir

I'm having space issues on my Vista machine and need to figure out what's taking up so much space.

I would like to write a simple batch file that returns all folders under C: and the size of each folder.

The **`dir`** command doesn't appear to return folder size.

Unfortunately we don't have admin rights and can't install a third party application and we have other users in our group that also need this information.

Comment: Not sure about how to do that, but can you run an application in place at all?

Comment: as long as i don't need administrator privileges i can run an app in place.

Comment: Windirstat can be run in place, one will need to go through the installer on a computer where they do have admin privileges (only cause the installer requests them). But can then just copy the exe and run it where needed.

Comment: get a rather nice visual tree of the file sizes too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd have a look at this thread for some clues as to how to achieve the directory size:

[Batch File To Display Directory Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759481/batch-file-to-display-directory-size)

Otherwise:

dirsize:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a value=0
set /a sum=0
FOR /R %1 %%I IN (*) DO (
set /a value=%%~zI/1024
set /a sum=!sum!+!value!
)
@echo %CD%:!sum! k
```

AllDirSize:

```
echo off
set WORKING_DIRECTORY=%cd%
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a:D /D /B /S') do (  
            echo off
            cd %%a
            "%WORKING_DIRECTORY%"\dirsize "%%a"
            cd %WORKING_DIRECTORY%
)
```

Use it: `ALLDIRSIZE > C:\temp\FileContainingFolderSizes.txt`

Which is taken from the excellent Richard Bishop testing forums: http://www.bish.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=58.0

Comment: @PaulWall - nice that it works for you. But would you like to explain how you avoid the error??

Answer (score 5):

Not exactly answering your question, but if you have GUI access I'd suggest using TreeSize:
http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml

If you prefer command line use du command from Unix utils:
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yeah I posted the link to TreeSize and then remembered that there is this nice port of all the essential unix utils!

Comment: I usually want to find the sizes of the folders (and all their contents) in the current directory.  On Windows I did `find . -maxdepth 1 -exec du -sh {} +` note make sure you are using the UnxUtils find (or gnuwin32) and not the built-in windows `find` (running `which find` will tell you which one you're using)