# How to get the size of a folder in bytes with batch

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

If I check for my folder's size I get this:

```
for %i in (*) do @set /a size+=%~zi
166576251665763016658914166589201665917416659428166596821665993616660190166601951666038416660487168652871687269016872716169860941698686116986931169872071698728616987313169875941698775316987908169884331700481717005585170056001700563417005891170059181700605117007696170076961700782617021650170218471702192817022003170220911702211617022141170222091702227017022755170228501702370517023960170242831702453617024848170252511702526817578552175800371758003717580037175800371758003717580037175826531758490317591537175919931759206017592095175921301764998617650665176520351765318217654163176541681772380017723825177251031772519925614095256149392561514625615899256181532599996926105233264957532672798526897833268979242689853526898590268986582689871926898790269001782690062626900643269008432690103926907695269077312690853826909921269100822691020226910240269105802691578626915899269343312693438226935123269842752698438326984697269990372701337927013912270139282701420927014362270144002701448427014572274675622746760127468336275041762753080027530915275319062753190627535850275367832756033527560455275605872756248927562632275846482783706427968251279696822797111327972544279739752797540627976865279782962797972727981158279811582805130228051656
echo %size%
28051656
```

But the dir command says the size is `1,907,481,021` bytes! What is going wrong? How can I get the right size? I have this [Batch file that returns folder size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4519320/2618542), but I don't want large  units as MB,GB. I want to put the size in a variable.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you meam `+=` instead of `=+`?

Comment: Yes sorry, was a copy and paste error. But the result is still not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, it reads the folder size with the `dir` command:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "tokens=3" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /-c') DO (
    SET size=!free!
    SET free=%%a
)
ECHO %size% bytes in %cd%
```

This works for European time format. For `AM/PM` format set `tokens=4`. 
This is a solution by Aacini.

Comment: I get the size not for 'c:\folder1\' and 'c:\folder2' ? I get always the size of the last folder :(

Comment: Look at the answer from LS_dev. For calculations > 2 GB you should use `awk` for Windows, or `Perl` [ActivePerl](http://www.activestate.com/activeperl).

Answer (score 4):

This returns the sum of the folder and its subdirectories.

```
@echo off
call :size "c:\folder1" 
call :size "c:\folder2" 
pause
goto :eof
:size
for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('dir /s "%~1" 2^>nul ^|find " File(s) "') do  set "n=%%b"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%c in ("%n%") do (
echo %%c%%d%%e%%f bytes [%n%] in "%~1"
)
```

Comment: What can I do to get It work with 'c:\folder1\' and 'c:\folder2' ? I gel always the size of the last folder :(

Comment: Yes, I see, but I can't get the sum from size:folder1+size:folder2, if size gtr 2GB. I will upvote your answer and maybe make a new question. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a arithmetic overflow. Check

```
 SET /A s=2147483647+1
```

Environment variable arithmetic is done over 32-bit signed integers.

So, maximum size you number you can sum safely is `2^31-1 = 2147483647`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to count in bytes, then you need to split your numbers to multiple variables.

Like lowCount the lower 8 digits and highCount the upper 8 digitis, so you get 16 digits with a resolution up 9999TBytes.

You only need to add a bit of math function to handle the big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Code for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for a set of folders stored in a text file:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "file=file"
SET /a allsize=0
for /f %%x in (
'for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in (%file%^) do @(
    for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ('dir /a-d /-c "%%~a" ^^^|findstr /BR "[0-9]"'^) do @ECHO(%%b^)'
) do (
    FOR /f %%i IN ('awk "BEGIN {a=%%x+!allsize!; print a}"') DO SET "allsize=%%i"
)
ECHO Size of all folders listet in %file%:
awk "BEGIN {a=%allsize%; printf(\"%%10d %%s\",a,\"bytes\n\")}"
awk "BEGIN {a=%allsize%/1024; printf(\"%%10d %%s\",a,\"KB\n\")}"
awk "BEGIN {a=%allsize%/1024/1024; printf(\"%%10d %%s\",a,\"MB\n\")}"
awk "BEGIN {a=%allsize%/1024/1024/1024; printf(\"%%10.2g %%s\",a,\"GB\n\")}"
```

Example:

```
Size of all folders listet in file:
1907481021 bytes
   1862774 KB
      1819 MB
       1.8 GB
```